# Regression: How to account for grouping among dependent variables

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, spss

updated to clarify what I'm asking...

I have a data set where each respondent provided a "rating" on multiple objects (i.e 50).  There are also attributes measured for each respondent (i.e. Age, Gender, etc.).  How can I account for variation in both the individual respondents and a "hierarchy" present among the dependent variables?...

The dependent variables are not allocated to equal size groups - therefore it is not a true repeated measures-like design.

Here's an example

```
    ID | Age | Gender | GPA | Object1_Group1 | Object2_ Group1 |  Object3_Group 2
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
     1 |  19 |      M |  2.8|     13.4       |       34.8      |      9.8
     2 |  22 |      F |  3.9|     23.7       |       2.5       |      12.6
```

just imagine that there are several groups, with varying numbers of objects in each group.  So group 1 might have 10 objects, group 2 might have 5 objects, group 3 could have 3 objects, and so on...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you ask a definite question?

Comment: How can I account for individual (rater) attributes and a grouping structure among multiple dependent variables?